# AMPPS Installation and Running

Tags: apache, ampps

I am new on web development,
I am starting on PHP and have downloaded Ampps stack, but nothing is working. the buttons do not toggle and Apache keep on saying "apache is already running on your machine, do you want to stop that instance and start AMPPS Apache?"

But after clicking yes, the same message comes back.

Help please

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0Qf9.jpg)

Comment: Better to uninstall that other apache service or configure the new one to use a different port at least.

Comment: Okay I will try to configure a new one, because I have already uninstalled it and it still did not work.

Comment: Thank you so much "Shadow" , I have configure the new one on a different port following this direction "https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/redash/administration/configure-port/" and its running now as well as Php.